# Каким образом в Laravel указать пути подгрузки кастомных ServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, autoload

В проекте используется компонентный подход. Что это значит? Что в основном приложении Laravel, создаются подпапки в `app\Classes\*Название компонента*`, где есть своя структура "мини-приложения".
И вот в этой структуре есть папочка `Services`, где лежат `ServiceProvider` для этого компонента.

Таких компонентов может быть десяток и возникает вопрос, можно ли как то через `autoload` их по приложению искать и загружать? Может, кто сталкивался с подобным

Comment: Не смотрели в сторону nwidart/laravel-modules?

Comment: @Walfter спасибо за наводку, посмотрю. Я думал как нибудь через composer autoload сделать, но пока ничего толком не нашел